# TYPO3 Formhandler "Attachment not found: !"

Tags: typo3

I was trying to implement the typo3-formhandler. I followed this tutorial: [How to set up a simple form](http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/articles-howtos/b/how-to-set-up-a-simple-form/)
step by step, but I keep getting this error:

> Attachment not found! Mail NOT sent to: [mail address]

I've made a couple of pictures of the whole debug log:
http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/tg5sjj9x/Bildschirmfoto.png
http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/f6btnnxq/Bildschirmfoto1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I haven't configured PHP's mail-Function on my server. I just assmued that formhandler would use TYPO3-Configuration, but it didn't.

Since Version 1.2, you can tell FormHandler to use TYPO3's config:
http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/release-notes/version-120/

Correct Typoscript-Script for the problem is:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {  
  debug = 1   
  templateFile = fileadmin/contactform/1-contactform.html  
  formValuesPrefix = formhandler   
  finishers {    
    1 {      
      class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail
      config {
        mailer.class = Mailer_TYPO3Mailer
      }
    }    
    2 {      
      class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_SubmittedOK      
      config.returns = 1    
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really tell where the error "“Attachment not found: !” comes from.